# First entry to USA on visit visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, multiple-entry

I have a 10 year Multiple entry visit visa to USA issued in April 2019. By what date shall I make the first entry to USA to keep the visa valid ?

Comment: What about by April 2029. But it all depends on the "condition of the visa" (not in your question. If your situation change sensibly (in worse) you may still have problem. Note: validity of visa do no mean you can enter to US. -- It is difficult to answer a very generic question in a precise way.

Comment: Anytime before it expires is the short answer. You don’t have to do anything to keep it valid or **activate** it.

Answer (score 5):

Your visa is already valid and does not need to be activated by travel. You do not need to keep to the original travel plans you described in your visa application. You can change or cancel these plans if necessary.

You can enter at any time on or before the expiry date of the visa. The expiry date is the last day that you can *enter* the US, not the date that you must *exit*. You can enter the US on the visa expiry date and be admitted for a full six months. Each time you enter the US, your passport will be stamped with the date of entry and the date you must exit. You need to leave the US before the end of the day of that date.

Each time you travel to the US, you must be going for one of the purposes permitted to tourists or business visitors (B1/B2). The visa allows you to travel to the US as many times as you wish, but it does not guarantee that you will be allowed to enter. You still must satisfy the officer at the border that you will adhere to the rules and leave the US without overstaying.

If your passport expires, the visa still remains valid. Travel with both your old and new passports in this case. When you renew your passport, be sure to ask your country's passport authority to return the old passport.

Answer (score 3):

The main offical site, shown below, does **not** meantion a first date of usage requirement.

Only that the passport must be valid 6 months after the expected exit and that an expired passport with a valid visa can be used with a new passport.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html

Comment: Most countries are actually exempted from the six-month requirement.